# Action depend select option value selected?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to change color of select box and its row depending on selected value of select box. Like i have tried there is 3 select box and 3 option selected on each combo.
How can i make color change on each option  selected on each select box?

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: purple;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary" selected>Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary" selected>Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional" selected>Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually i want result like this? [image]
About custom select box i will manage. Its all about adding specific class for different color.

Comment: About custombox i will manage. I just need to add specific class depending on select option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using javascript (jQuery's) `change` event on `select` and use `closest()` for parent selection, like:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  if(value == 'Primary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('primary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('secondary optional');
  } else if(value == 'Secondary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('secondary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary optional');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('optional');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary secondary');
  }
});
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  if(text == 'Primary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('primary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('secondary optional');
  } else if (text == 'Secondary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('secondary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary optional');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('optional');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary secondary');
  }
});

$('body').on('change', 'select', function() {
  var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  if(value == 'Primary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('primary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('secondary optional');
  } else if(value == 'Secondary') {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('secondary');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary optional');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').addClass('optional');
    $(this).parent().closest('.row').removeClass('primary secondary');
  }
});


$('#btnAddEmpField').on('click', function(){
 $('.emp-customize-form').append("<div class='row secondary'>\
  <div class='col'>\
    <select id='impSelect1'>\
      <option value='primary'>Primary</option>\
      <option value='secondary' selected>Secondary</option>\
      <option value='optional'>Optional</option>\
    </select>\
  </div>\
</div>");
})
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: purple;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.primary {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.secondary {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}

.optional {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emp-customize-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <select id="impSelect1">
        <option value="primary" selected>Primary</option>
        <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
        <option value="optional">Optional</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <select id="impSelect2">
        <option value="primary">Primary</option>
        <option value="secondary" selected>Secondary</option>
        <option value="optional">Optional</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <select id="impSelect3">
        <option value="primary">Primary</option>
        <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
        <option value="optional" selected>Optional</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<span id="btnAddEmpField">add</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yea, it helps me a lot..

Thanks bro

Comment: Its my pleasure @Kumar

Comment: yes, it works i need to add row on click on add button too. I have added script for append row on click add button but its not working on appended row. http://jsfiddle.net/7jznjqax/1/

Comment: can you help me bro?

Comment: @Kumar I've updated my code, please have a look or see the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7jznjqax/2/ . Please let me know if this works?

Comment: Yes, its working.. Thanks a lot
I accept your answer and thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Keep a color dict and accordingly change color on change of select box. Below is the sample code:

```js
var color = {'primary':'red', 'secondary': 'blue', 'optional':'gray'};

$('.impSelect').click(function(){
$(this).css('background-color', color[$(this).val()]);
});
$('.impSelect').click();
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: purple;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect" class="impSelect">
      <option value="primary" selected>Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect" class="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary" selected>Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect" class="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional" selected>Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its very cool brow... Can we make via adding class on parent? And thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Do the `addClass` when change the function of the select button.For adding class to the parent .Target the `row` class using [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii2Y3s5pzXAhWLNI8KHUvpATcQFgjBATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AOvVaw2teuWSoGd9ftcB4VI_FyL2) jquery function

```js
$('.row').on('change','select',function(){
$(this).attr('class','').addClass($(this).val()).closest('.row').attr('class','row').addClass($(this).val())
})
$(function(){
$('.row select').each(function(){
$(this).attr('class','').addClass($(this).val()).closest('.row').attr('class','row').addClass($(this).val())
})
})
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: purple;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.primary{
background-color:red;
}
.optional{
background-color:blue;
}
.secondary{
background-color:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary" selected>Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary" selected>Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional" selected>Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of doing so would be to bind a `change` event handler to the targeted select elements. In the snippet below I have bound to all `select` elements, but you can select them through a CSS class or through descendent selectors.

Then, you can define CSS classes to give required styles to the select. In the snippet, I have kept the CSS class names equal to the intended value of the select. Hence adding a class `primary` to the `select` would apply red background and white color.

```
select.primary {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

So when the value in the `select` change, you just remove existing classes on it, and apply the new class.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  // Remove the other classes.
  $(this).attr("class","");

  // Add the new class as per the value selected.
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).addClass(value);
});

// Apply the colors initially.
$("select").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).addClass(value);
});
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: purple;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

select.primary {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

select.secondary {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

select.optional {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary" selected>Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary" selected>Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional">Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select id="impSelect">
      <option value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
      <option value="optional" selected>Optional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare colors in your stylesheet with the same classes as the name of select options. For eg.

   `.mandatory { background: red; color: white;}
   .optional { background: purple; color: white;}`
2. Assign the class on select change using jQuery

   `$(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').on('change', function(){
         var thisSelect = $(this);
         var optionSelected = thisSelect.find("option:selected");
         var optionName = optionSelected.attr('value');
         thisSelect.removeClass().addClass(optionName);
      });
   });`